# Exception when using df.apply on empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have code that is similar to what I've provided below but the problem is it exceptions when the dataframe is empty.

```
raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

```py
df['Started'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'yes' if x['current_page'] > 0 else 'no', axis = 1)
```

Is there a way to write this `apply` so that it doesn't exception out other than wrapping it in an if check?

```py
if (not df.empty):
    df['Started'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'yes' if x['current_page'] > 0 else 'no', axis = 1)
```

Comment: don't use `apply`, use `df['Started'] = np.where(df['current_page'] > 0, 'yes', 'no')`

Comment: Thank you, just to understand you edited your comment and switched out select with where. Why?

Comment: because `where` should be used, `select` is for multiple conditions ;)

Comment: the actual issue is due to the fact that you use `apply` on a DataFrame btw, but in any case `apply` is not needed here